# How to resize an image to fit its container with CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am currently doing the Freecodecamp course, but I got a little stuck on one of the projects. This is the current state of my project: https://codepen.io/otapadar/full/JjRaoex (I am trying to copy this website: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNBOYG).  The second section (My Projects) has images within a grid. I am trying to resize the images, such that each image covers about 80-90% of the parent element, just like the site I am trying to copy.

When you look at my website, you see that the images are not resizing. I have tried fixing this by using the following property on my images: object-fit: cover. This doesn't fix it, sadly.

Any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1>Hey, I am Brad</h1>
    <p>Web Developer</p>
  </section>
  <section id="projects">
    <h2 class="projects-header">My Projects</h2>
    <container class="project-grid">
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg">
        <p class="project-title">Tribute Page</p>
      </a>
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/random-quote-machine.png">
        <p class="project-title">Random Quote Machine</p>
      </a>
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/calc.png">
        <p class="project-title">JavaScript Calculator</p>
      </a>
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/map.jpg">
        <p class="project-title">Map Data</p>
      </a>
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/wiki.png">
        <p class="project-title">Wikipedia Viewer</p>
      </a>
      <a class="project-tile" target="_blank">
        <img class="project-image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/images/tic-tac-toe.png">
        <p class="project-title">Tic Tac Toe</p>
      </a>
    </container>
    <a class="button" href="https://codepen.io/otapadar" target="_blank">Show All</a>
  </section>
  <section id="contact">
    <h1>Let's Work Together</h1>
    <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
    <container class="social-icons">
      <a class="profile-link" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="profile-link" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="profile-link" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="profile-link" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="profile-link" target="_blank"></a>
    </container>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #be3144;
}

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%)
}

#welcome-section > h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

#welcome-section > p {
  color: #be3144;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#projects {
  background-color: #45567d;
  padding: 6rem 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.projects-header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem auto;
}

.project-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.project-tile {
  background-color: #303841;
}

.project-image {
  height: calc(100%-6rem);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.project-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #303841; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your css is this line `height: calc(100%-6rem);` just add spaces around the operator to be `height: calc(100% - 6rem);`

Comment: Hey Zac, do you also happen to know why my images aren't zoomed in enough like the website I am trying to copy? Take a look at the world map image for example. Can't seem to figure out what else I am doing wrong. Appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: I can see that for the '.project-grid' you need to adjust the grid props to be 3 items per row instead for 4, also it should be a 'div', container is not a valid html tag, 
then for '.project-image' elements, you need to correct "display: cover;" to be "object-fit: cover", 
in general, when you feel that your code should work fine try to debug and trace each part carefully to see what causes the difference between the expected and the actual results

Answer (score 1):

you should take white space after and befor minis like that

```css
height:calc(100% - 6rem)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you also happen to know why my images aren't zoomed in enough like the website I am trying to copy? Take a look at the world map image for example. Can't seem to figure out what else I am doing wrong. Appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: you should replace display to object-fit. if you want more info [check it](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Answer (score 0):

add max-width:100%;  to project-image class in css and also you can set a  custom width or height in img element

```css
    project-image{
 height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  max-width:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```